# History of category theory

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, math-history

I am searching some information about the origins of the category theory. Anyone know where can I read about those topics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a whole Wikipedia page: [Timeline of category theory and related mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_category_theory_and_related_mathematics). Also see the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-theory/#2). You might find [this](http://philmat.oxfordjournals.org/content/13/1/1.full) interesting as well.

Answer (score 5):

[From A Geometrical Point of View: A Study of the History and Philosophy of Category Theory](http://www.springer.com/philosophy/epistemology+and+philosophy+of+science/book/978-1-4020-9383-8).

Answer (score 4):

Each chapter in Mac Lane's CWM (Categories for the Working Mathematician) ends with some notes on the history of the relevant notions.

Comment: What means CWN? I did not know that author.

Comment: Mac Lane's Categories for the Working Mathematician is maybe THE standard book in category theory.

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead I also like Awodey, but that's getting off-topic.

Comment: @CameronJWhitehead there's no "maybe" there.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Sorry,guys. MacLane's classic will soon be joining Whitiker and Watson and van der Wearden in the dustbin of textbooks. It's been superseded by  Emily Riehl's CATEGORY THEORY IN CONTEXT. A remarkable,game changing textbook for graduate students and serious undergraduates that's not only as comprehensive and more up to date then MacLane, but has quite literally THOUSANDS  of examples,many unusual and insightful. I'll be reviewing it soon at my blog. But for my money,that's the gold standard now. And much CHEAPER then MacLane!

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Really, thousands? In 223 pages of text? I guess if you count each group as a separate example of a category.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the book [Tool and Object: A History and Philosophy of Category Theory](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-7643-7524-9) I have found some obscure things over there. Hope it helps.

Edit (2024/03/26): I forgot I answered this question a while ago, no long after I read the first article in the proceedings of Ross Street's 60th birthday celebration/conference titled [The beginnings of category theory in Australia](https://dx.doi.org/10.1090/conm/431/08263) by Max Kelly. Very insightful piece of history I would say!